# How to access DeviceId (IMEI) from Android using C++ Builder XE7/FMX?

Tags: android, c++builder, imei, c++builder-xe7

The following [video tutorial](http://firemonkeytutorial.com/full-access-android-ios-api-using-delphi-firemonkey/) was a good starting point (using Vibrator as an example rather than DeviceId), but there were a few more details needing attention to transpose to C++.

I'm just getting started with Stack Exchange.  Hopefully this question and answer is useful to others; the following code does work as expected.

```
#include <Androidapi.Helpers.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.Telephony.hpp>

// Get Device ID (IMEI) from device:
_di_JObject TelephonyServiceObj = SharedActivityContext()->getSystemService(TJContext::JavaClass->TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
_di_JTelephonyManager TelephonyManager = TJTelephonyManager::Wrap(((_di_ILocalObject)TelephonyServiceObj)->GetObjectID());
UnicodeString DeviceId = JStringToString(TelephonyManager->getDeviceId());
```

Comment: I'm confused, what is your question?

Comment: I already found the answer, but not easily as there are not yet many examples of using C++ Builder to access Android API.  I am new to Stack Exchange and won't post any more questions with answers.  As always, two implied questions: Is there a better answer and a better reference?

Comment: It would be better if you cleaned up the question so it reads like a question, then posted the answer to the question *as an answer*. It is perfectly ok to answer your own question, but try not to blur the lines.

Comment: The include files referenced in the code snippet above don't exist. I checked  in android_5.1.1_r3 and android-6.0.0_r1, downloaded from the Google AOSP site.